# Entity Framework 6 One-Way relationship using Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-6

I have the following scenario:

1. Color Class

   ```
   public int ID
   {
       get;
       set;
   }

   public string Name
   {
       get;
       set;
   }

   public string Hex
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
   ```
2. Widget Class

   ```
   public int ID
   {
       get;
       set;
   }

   public int HeaderBackgroundColorID
   {
       get;
       set;
   }

   public Color HeaderBackgroundColor
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
   ```

Using Code-First, I am trying to create a one-way relationship between Widget to Color classes with the **HeaderBackgroundColor / HeaderBackgroundColorID** Fields.

normally i would do this in the config class:

```
this.HasOptional(r => r.HeaderBackgroundColor )
    .WithMany(m => m.Widgets)
    .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.HeaderBackgroundColorID);
```

but i am not intrested in adding a Widgets collection to the Color class.
tried this:

```
this.HasOptional(r => r.HeaderBackgroundColor )
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.HeaderBackgroundColorID);
```

but that throws a validation error.

What's the way to do this right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting an error because `HeaderBackgroundColorId` is a non-nullable `int`, so it cannot be optional.

All you need to do to achieve what you're looking for is to turn the foreign key into a nullable `int`...

```
public int? HeaderBackgroundColorID { get; set; }
```

Because you named the foreign key to match the navigation property (`HeadBackgroundColorId` and `HeaderBackgroundColor`) which follows Code First conventions, you do not need to create any explicit mappings. Simply making the above change will make the relationship optional.

Comment: Well that was indeed part of the problem. the other issue was that i did not mark HeaderBackgroundColor as a Virtual property.